# GD library with multiple image formats

Tags: php, image-resizing

I'm using a gd library script to resize images that are uploaded.

- All images that are uploaded are renamed with a .jpg extension.
- When the original images is .jpg or .jpeg, I can see the image and resize it without any issues.
- But when the original image is a .gif or a .png, I cannot view or resize the image
- I'll get an error, "JPEG library reports unrecoverable error.. $filename is not a valid JPEG file"
- This is the line that tells it to look for jpg/jpeg file:

  ```
  $func = 'imagecreatefrom' . ($ext == 'jpg' ? 'jpeg' : $ext);
  ```
- If the original is a .png, if I replace the 'jpeg' above with 'png', then it works, but obviously, it no longer works with .jpg files

My question, how can I modify the line above to specify for jpg, jpeg, png and gif?

I tried this, but it wouldn't work (syntax error):

`$func = 'imagecreatefrom' . ($ext == 'jpg' ? 'jpeg' ? 'png' ? 'gif' : $ext);`

Here's the full portion of the code:

```
function loadImage($filename)
{
    $ext  = strtolower($this->_getExtension($filename));
    $func = 'imagecreatefrom' . ($ext == 'jpg' ? 'jpeg' : $ext);
    if (!$this->_isSupported($filename, $ext, $func, false)) {
        return false;
    }

    $this->_imgOrig = $func($filename);
    if ($this->_imgOrig == null) {
        $this->_debug("The image could not be created from the '$filename' file using the '$func' function.");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: if I got your questions correctly - you simple could wrap this line in separate function were you will have some switch statement for all variant you have png, jpeg and gif.

Comment: If you cannot make a ternary operator work then use a simple set of IF statements or as above a switch